# SqlException: Ambiguous column name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting this error when the code below is run:

> Ambiguous column name 'AppointmentID'.
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Ambiguous column name 'AppointmentID'.
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 68:          adapter.Fill(tbl);

This is the function that causes the error:

```
public Transaction Payment
{
    get
    {
        return Db.Transaction.FindWhere("[AppointmentID]=@0 AND [Type]='paym'", SqlDb.Params(this.ID));
    }
}
```

Transaction structure:

```
public partial class Transaction : SqlRow
{
    public int CID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public int? AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: We need to see your table structure (Transaction).

Comment: Either AppointmentId or Type is used in more than one table (assuming there is a join). Fully qualify the column name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception says it all. There is more than one column with name `AppointmentID` in different tables. You can either use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx) or use `[TableName].[AppointmentID]` in your query.

You should share your SQL code for more concrete help.

Answer (score 2):

Look over your query. The column AppointmentID in multiple table.

You must use table aliases look [there](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)

## For Example :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(    
   ID int,    
   AppointmentID int,    
   FirstName  varchar(255)
 );

 CREATE TABLE Table2 
 (    
    ID int,    
    AppointmentID int,    
    LastName  varchar(255)
 );

 Select A.FirstName , A.AppointmentID  , B.LastName , B.AppointmentID  
   From Table1 A, Table2 B   
  Where A.AppointmentID  = B.AppointmentID ;
```